# '{{FSharpCoreShippedPackageVersion}}' is not a valid version string

Tags: .net-core, f#, visual-studio-2019

I just upgraded to Visual Studio 2019 version 16.5.0 Preview 2.0.  It seems to have broken building and running .NET Core projects in F# with the `dotnet` command line tool.

Previously `dotnet build` and `dotnet run` worked fine.  Now either one produces this error message (wrapped for readability):

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.200-preview-014883\NuGet.targets(124,5):
  error : '{{FSharpCoreShippedPackageVersion}}' is not a valid version string.
```

My projects don't have the string `FSharpCoreShippedPackageVersion` anywhere in them that I can see (including in the .fsproj files).  I also looked in the referenced NuGet.targets file and couldn't find `FSharpCoreShippedPackageVersion` in it either.

Using `dotnet new console --language=F#` also fails, telling me to restore NuGet packages, but attempting `dotnet restore` gives the same error message.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**UPDATE**: This issue appears to be fixed in the current version of the preview:

`3.1.200-preview-014977`

If you update Visual Studio 2019 Preview, you shouldn't need this workaround anymore.

---

I found a workaround:

1. Run `dotnet new globaljson` in the project root folder
2. Edit the global.json to use .NET Core **3.1.101** instead of `3.1.200-preview-014883`.

It appears that the combination of VS 2019 Version 16.5.0 Preview 2.0 and .NET Core `3.1.200-preview-014883` causes this problem.

Comment: There's a github issue now, too: https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/issues/2063.